# How to find objects in floor plan image in Tkinter python through svg file?

Tags: python, svg, tkinter, vectorization, raster

I have a vectorized floorplan image. I want to identify the objects in the image through the vector data in the SVG file of that image. The SVG code does not have any close points(z) in between them. So I am unable to understand when does the point moves to the other object? Can somebody help me, please?

I have very little knowledge about these SVG files and using them in Tkinter. So please somebody help me or suggest me what can I do?

This is the vector data of the image.
[vector data of the image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Js68MZgBmvjgG7og_AUqhDcKHaOOOExP/view?usp=sharing,%20https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ory2iG2Q9XzuKXNEwG0-vlqmAr_c7jQS/view?usp=sharing)

[image: This is the floor plan image]

Comment: Try searching for `M` (moveto) in the path string.

Comment: But what about those objects which have concentric shapes in it like the object at the top left corner?  When the point moves to inner or outer rectangle, it should be considered as one object.

Comment: Your svg is all one object. Think of it as **all** being drawn with the pen drawing it with one very long stroke (even despite you seeing non-contiguous shapes). This is **extremely** typical of architectural drawings which are not thought of in an object oriented context. As above find the M (moveto). Some objects will have multiple moves. Try / character before the letter in path, it will blank out rest of the path drawing (**very, very** handy tip) so you can work out what it going on.

Comment: could you please tell me is there any way to get the bounding boxes(coordinates of bounding boxes) around the objects?

Comment: There is no object related information, just groups of lines.  You need to find a way to combine related groups of lines as an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use in conjunction with [SO floorplan question](https://github.com/owaine1/stackoverflow_floorplan).
Jump to [z_final_floorplan.svg](https://github.com/owaine1/stackoverflow_floorplan/blob/master/z_final_floorplan.svg?short_path=9620e31) for final file.

---

A
Create 4 files:

```
w_original_floorplan.svg  
x_rough_static_floorplan.svg  
y_rough_live_floorplan.svg  
z_final_floorplan.svg
```

w_original_floorplan.svg and x_rough_static_floorplan.svg are identical apart from filename.
y_rough_live_floorplan.svg and z_final_floorplan.svg are empty; to be populated.

Copy x_rough_static_floorplan.svg to y_rough_live_floorplan.svg.
Open y_rough_live_floorplan.svg on browser using server.

x_rough_static_floorplan.svg find all M and replace with two newlines / symbol M (case sensitive). shift + enter shift + enter /M

---

B
[this section takes the time]
Take away 1st '/' in path in y_rough_live_floorplan.svg [shows blackout_floorplan]
Label x_rough_static_floorplan.svg code section blackout_floorplan where code is.
(this file is used as rough-work, so being xml / svg valid is irrelevant)

In y_rough_live_floorplan.svg find next '/' and delete it [shows floorplan_top_left_whiteout]
Label x_rough_static_floorplan.svg code section floorplan_top_left_whiteout where code is.

Have x_rough_static_floorplan.svg and y_rough_live_floorplan.svg open in 2 windows, will be going back and forth to each of them. Keep repeating until at end.

(hint: find tool seems to be on switching from files in vscode, so you can use find / and next one cmd + g easily) Maybe handy to have a paper printout of original svg as reference and label the names of objects you create e.g.bath, sink, table, as you go along (don’t be fooled by this, one table is 'table'. Is 2nd chair chair2, chair_2, chair_two etc.?) etc..

---

C
Reorder the whole labels and corresponding code in path x_rough_static_floorplan.svg so the labels are ordered next to each other, but in the order they are found in the path:
e.g.
…
floorplan
bath
sink
table_chairs
sofa
…

Use the 'find' tool here. This process, itself will require a temp file to copy and paste to rather than reorder within the file working on. And rewrite temp to file working on. Might be good idea to create checklist of objects and cross-off as done.
E.g. floorplan, bath, table_chairs, sink…

---

D
Create path elements from your grouped objects, putting each id as id=“floorplan_main”, id=“bath”, id=“sink” etc.. etc..

---

Bear in mind, the data of how this is drawn is really, really bad. Really they should be drawn with rect elements for a rectangle when possible and a lot of the path data is very unnecessary, but that’s obviously how the application generates the svg.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I did not understand clearly the 'B' step. Could you please explain once again? I did not understand what we have to do with x and y files alternatively. Do both the files should have /M initially?

Comment: B is about: you now have `M 9 5 ...whatever` separated by 2 lines. You're working off a number of similar files.  You're labeling what each `M` is here, whether it's a table or chair. I did start labelling too much in detail in the github file, so maybe it wouldn't make as much sense as I intended. And I made some mistakes in the middle and decided to just get to the final file. I'll see if I can revise it later. Yes both files have /M initially. You're taking off each '/' to reveal the next thing.

Comment: Ok revised the `x_...` files. My labeling at fault. End result of `x_d...` still buggy but `z_final...` works